# Difference between "should", "would" and "ought to"

Tags: differences, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

The sentence:

> It's essential that the documents **should** be destroyed
>   immediately.

Why can't **ought to** be used in place of **should** and why can't I go for **would**?

Comment: It's essential that you choose a relevant title for your question. :)

Comment: Because in [mandative subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) constructions, the U.S. typically uses a bare infinitive (i.e., the subjunctive) while the U.K. typically uses *should*. And your grammar book is teaching you U.K. English. Why do we use these forms? I think it's the end result of a complicated historical process which started with *should be* and *be* being two alternative subjunctive constructions.

Comment: With the death of the subjunctive, I believe *are* is becoming a widely used alternative in the U.K. (Although I'm not sure about this, because I speak U.S. English.) But I believe that options b, c, d are not generally used. [See this reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=%22essential+that+he+is%22&source=bl&ots=mLDXZcjXYy&sig=eyRpvGX4d-3nHZ2qvpfcMzwtVLk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiwIrs6O3KAhXB7D4KHZswD2UQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22essential%20that%20he%20is%22&f=false).

Comment: @PeterShor Do you mean that you would insert no word at all? *It is essential that the documents be destroyed*. Because I would find that equally idiomatic. I am not at all sure that I would use *should* - except perhaps for emphasis.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, in formal English, Americans would typically insert no word at all.

Comment: It partly depends on the exact context. If we know we're in a context where there are multiple possible plans under consideration, but the need to destroy those documents only applies to one specific plan currently being addressed in detail, ***would*** would be perfectly natural to me (since it's referencing an "irrealis" hypothetical situation that may not even be *selected*, let alone put into practice).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Are you able to elaborate a bit more on that, perhaps with the whole sentence? I can conceive of *It would be essential that the documents be destroyed*; but I'm having trouble with*It is essential that the documents would be destroyed...*

Comment: It is essential that whoever concocted that test be destroyed immediately.

Comment: @WS2: If you don't accept, say, *If we decide to go down that route, it's essential any illegal accomplices would be well-paid to ensure their silence*, I doubt there's anything I could say that would change your mind. But on reflection, the fact that ***I*** would "tolerate" it doesn't necessarily imply it's "grammatical". So I'll cancel my downvote to your answer, since we're talking about "acceptability", not "strict grammar".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd feel more comfortable with *...it would be essential that any illegal accomplices be well-paid...* And congratulations on scoring a century - a considerable achievement!

Comment: @WS2: Since the beginning of the year I'd been throwing out another bounty every time I got close (didn't want to stick my head *too* far above the parapet! :). But then my [pipe dream](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/304016/2637) caught the attention of the SO multicollider overnight and crashed me right through my self-imposed glass ceiling. Rather endearingly, I got an email from SO a couple of days later asking for my real-world name and address, so they can send me a T-shirt (I'm hoping it'll say ***I couldn't afford a funny one***, but I know that's a long shot! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well done. Nice to see that the UK has two of the top three. I haven't seen anything from Barrie England for a long time. If he has retired you must be the presumed authority on the Queen's English. More than a T shirt, you may be in for an OBE!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! They are really helpful! Especially this one:" 
It is essential that whoever concocted that test be destroyed immediately. ":)))))))– Hot Licks 19 hours ago

Answer (score 6):

The only one that fits grammatically is *should*.

Another idiomatic possibility is to insert no word at all - *It is essential that the documents be destroyed immediately*.

*Ought to be*, *would* and *had better* cannot be qualified by *it is essential that...*

If something *ought to be done* it ought to be done. It is not gradable and subject to essentiality qualifications. Similarly with *had better*.

If it *would* be done, it is outside the scope of anyone to alter anything - so essential/inessential does not apply.